# Is it possible to use Alglib with Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp, alglib

I often use Rcpp code to incorporate C++ code into R. Through the BH-package I am also able to use the Boost-library. However, the Boost library lacks a function that I would like to use (to be precise, it only has Bessel function but I would like to get Log-Bessel immediately because of overflow). I know that [Alglib](http://www.alglib.net/) does have this feature.

Would it be possible to use Alglib with Rcpp, that is, use the log-bessel function from Alglib somehow?

Comment: The question "is it possible" is obviously "yes", since Alglib is C++. There isn't a wrapper already that I know of, so how to do that is too broad for SO, unless you have specific problems.  Whether you need to do it is another question: are R's Bessel functions not OK http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/bessel? The alglib Bessel functions look very similar http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#unit_bessel

Comment: Is the question how to use some package for C++ in Rcpp too broad for SO? In that case, I am sorry, but I really do not know where I could find information that would help me get the Alglib library working within Rcpp. 

The R functions would be ok, but as far as I am aware I would not be able to use the R function within my Rcpp-based C++ code because that requires the developers of Rcpp to add this function to Rcpp.

Comment: You can of course call any R function (easily) in Rcpp code, with the obvious overhead cost.

Comment: I can? I was under the impression that I could only call specific 'sugar' functions from your C++, which I thought because the [Quick Reference](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-quickref.pdf) and [Hadley's guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) seem to imply this. How would I call an arbitrary R function from C++?

Comment: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/r-function-from-c++/

Comment: Thanks so much! I suppose I could pass the log-bessel function like this. If I get this right, though, the overhead would almost certainly be crippling for my code, so that Alglib would still be by far preferable, but I'll do some tests. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, Rcpp is for *extending* R with C++ code. Why don't you just create a package interfacing Alglib, or just carry the one Bessel function over?

Comment: Both of those things seem like good ideas, but I don't have enough  experience with Rcpp to come up with or implement either of those currently. Carrying only the Log-Bessel function over seems difficult because there seem to be lots of dependencies that lead I-don't-know-where. Would love to read up on both options more, though. I suppose I will try to go through the documentation again to find more about creating packages for interfacing. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a clear difference in functionality between the

- [AlgLib documentation on Bessel functions](http://www.alglib.net/specialfunctions/bessel.php), and
- [Boost documentation on Bessel functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/bessel.html).

As such, I think you can just use the [BH package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/bh.html) giving you all of Boost Math and then some.

Last but not least there is a [package bessel on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Bessel/index.html) written by the R Core member focusing on special functions so you could start from there too.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I was misinformed that AlgLib contained a LogBessel function, this seems to be openTURNS instead.  A bit embarrassing, I must admit. I was using the BH package before, but I was running into overflow issues, which is why I wanted to get a package that would allow Log-Bessel. I will look into the R package as well. Thanks!