# Rcpp programming efficiency

Tags: c++, arrays, rcpp

I am a beginner with Rcpp. Currently I wrote a Rcpp code, which was applied on two 3 dimensional arrays: `Array1` and `Array2`. Suppose `Array1` has dimension (1000, 100, 40) and `Array2` has dimension (1000, 96, 40).

I would like to perform `wilcox.test` using:

```
wilcox.test(Array1[i, j,], Array2[i,,])
```

In *R*, I wrote nested `for` loops that completed the calculation in about a half hour.

Then, I wrote it into Rcpp. The calculation within Rcpp took an hour to achieve the same results. I thought it should be faster since it is written in C++ language. I guess that my style of coding is the cause of the low efficient.

The following is my Rcpp code, would you mind helping me find out what improvement should I make please? I appreciate it!

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector Cal(NumericVector Array1,NumericVector Array2,Function wilc) {

  NumericVector vecArray1(Array1);
  IntegerVector arrayDims1 = vecArray1.attr("dim");

  NumericVector vecArray2(Array2);
  IntegerVector arrayDims2 = vecArray2.attr("dim");

  arma::cube cubeArray1(vecArray1.begin(), arrayDims1[0], arrayDims1[1],      arrayDims1[2], false);

  arma::cube cubeArray2(vecArray2.begin(), arrayDims2[0], arrayDims2[1], arrayDims2[2], false);

  arma::mat STORE=arma::mat(arrayDims1[0], arrayDims1[1]); 

  for(int i=0;i<arrayDims1[1];i++)
  { 

    for(int j=0;j<arrayDims1[0];j++){
      arma::vec       v_cl=cubeArray1.subcube(arma::span(j),arma::span(i),arma::span::all);

      //arma::mat      tem=cubeArray2.subcube(arma::span(j),arma::span::all,arma::span::all);

      //arma::vec v_ct=arma::vectorise(tem);

      arma::vec   v_ct=arma::vectorise(cubeArray2.subcube(arma::span(j),arma::span::all,arma::span::all));

      Rcpp::List resu=wilc(v_cl,v_ct);
      STORE(j,i)=resu[2];

    }

  }


  return(Rcpp::wrap(STORE));

}
```

The function `wilc` will be `wilcox.test` from *R*.

The following is part of my *R* code for implementing the above idea, where `CELLS` and `CTRLS` are two 3D array in *R*.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(CELLS)) {
  if(T){ print(i) }
  for (j in 1:dim(CELLS)[1]) {
    wtest = wilcox.test(CELLS[j,i,], CTRLS[j,,])
    TSTAT_clcl[j,i] = wtest$p.value
  }
}
```

Comment: Calling R from C++ inside each loop is ... pretty much the same as writing in R.  You had the wrong starting assumption: the loops you rewrote were not the bottleneck.  Next time, maybe profile first.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, thank you for your comment! I rewrote it in R using foreach and use doSNOW to implement code parallel. Now given a 1000*100*40 array, it takes 18 minutes to get a result. However it is still not ideal. It is very challenge for someone who lacks computer science knowledge like me to try to improve the performance of the code. Anyway, I find it also interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then, I wrote it into Rcpp. The calculation within Rcpp took an hour to achieve the same results. I thought it should be faster since it is written in C++ language.

The required disclaimer:

Embedding *R* code in *C++* and expecting a speed up is a fool's game. You will need to rewrite `wilcox.test` full in *C++* instead of making a call to *R*. Otherwise, you lose whatever speed up advantage you get.

In particular, I wrote up a [post](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-to-armadillo-using-rcpparmadillo-for-speed-and-portability/) illustrating this conundrum regarding the using the `diff` function in *R*. Within the post, I detailed comparing a *pure* *C++* implementation, an *C++* implementation using an *R* function within the routine, and a pure *R* implementation. Stealing the `microbenchmark` illustrates the above issue.

```
expr        min     lq      mean        median  uq      max         neval
arma_fun    26.117  27.318  37.54248    28.218  29.869  751.087     100
r_fun       127.883 134.187 212.81091   138.390 151.148 1012.856    100
rcpp_fun    250.663 265.972 356.10870   274.228 293.590 1430.426    100
```

Thus, a *pure* *C++* implementation had the largest speed up.

Hence, the take away is the need to translate the [`wilcox.test`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/stats/R/wilcox.test.R) *R* routine code to a pure *C++* implementation to drop the run time. Otherwise, it is meaningless to write the code in *C++* because the *C++* component must **stop** and await results from *R* before continuing. This traditionally has a *lot* of overhead to ensure the data is well protected.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found a Wilcoxon signed-rank test implemented in C++  [ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/hypothesistesting/wilcoxonsignedrank.php). May I have your opinion about this? Does it worth a try? I appreciate it.

Comment: There isn't presently a wrapper to use ALGLIB within the _R_ ecosystem. (c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775923/is-it-possible-to-use-alglib-with-rcpp) You will likely have to implement it yourself.

Comment: That's a bad news. Anyway thank you very much! It is my first time asking question on this website, I did not expect I could get feedback so quickly, thank you @coatless !

Comment: @SongTang Seems that you are a lucky guy and somebody else already did the work of reimplementation, check this out: https://github.com/stenver/wilcoxon-test.

Comment: Hi @Dominik, thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately that code is implemented under Linux system. I am currently using Windows. Anyway, Rcpp is really a powerful tool!

Comment: @SongTang This is unfortunate. You might then consider to re-implement it yourself, the algorithm seems to be not too difficult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test.