# Apply a function from package "BioQC" in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

In my previous question [My previous question which may be relevant to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292546/rcpp-programming-efficiency), I called `wilcox.test` in Rcpp.

(`wilcox.test` is a default method in R and it was written in R, the source code can be found here: [Source code of wilcox.test in R](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/wilcox.test.R))

The speed of the code is very slow because of `Embedding R code in C++`. I was suggested to write `wilcox.test` in Rcpp from the ground up.

Currently, I found an R package `BioQC` which was written in Rcpp and it offered a more efficient way for doing Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney rank sum test.

I am curious that since `BioQC` was written in Rcpp, is it possible to transfer their source code into my Rcpp code? What kind of file should I look into?

Here is their souce code which is relevant to Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney rank sum test:[BioQC source code](https://github.com/Accio/BioQC/blob/master/src/wmw_test.c)

I am interested in the first function **"wmw_test_stat"**, how should I transfer it into my Rcpp file?(I guess that just copy that code into Rcpp is obviously not enough).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The technical answer is that you _properly exported_ functions from one package can be called from another.  But that depends on whether BioQC makes it code callable from another package.  Details in the Writing R Extensions manual.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, thanks a lot! I will have a look at that.